# Delay UITableView vertical scroll when horizontal slider view is touched

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have a image slider view as headerview in tableview and when user tries to slide images horizontally, sometimes tableview vertical scrolling activates and moves view vertically.

I dont wanna disable tableview vertical scroll when user touches the image slider.

What i want is if touch is in imageslider area, and it has small vertical movement like 0-50px ignore it and if its more than 50px, allow it for vertical movement. To visualize my point:

[image]

I can detect touches and check their directions and after that disable tableview scrolling but i am not sure if it is the best method to go with. Is there any official or efficient way to handle this kind of problem?

Comment: I'd go with your method itself.

Comment: Hey @Arun, thx for reply. I was gonna start doing my method but I was afraid that might be an easier way like setting tableview property or better way to achieve it. So i will wait for a while if anyone has a better idea about it.

Comment: I am looking the same functionality for my app too. If I find any better, I will post her.